# Triggering limit order in Pine Script

Tags: json, pine-script

I've created a strategy on a 1 minute timeframe chart that triggers limit orders as soon as it find a candlestick pattern. How can I attach the limit price I want to enter the market in the POST request sent with the alert?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly. There are some placeholders which you can use to include a variable in your alert message, "limit" is not one of them.

However, you should be able to plot your limit levels on the chart. If you are able to do that, you can take advantage of `{{plot_n}}` placeholder.

> 5. {{plot_0}}, {{plot_1}}, ... {{plot_19}} - corresponding output series of an indicator used in the alert. Note that the plots are
>    numbered from zero. The highest plot ID is 19 (you can access only 20
>    first output series). Output series are the values of an indicator you
>    can see on a chart. For example, the built-in volume indicator has two
>    output series: Volume and Volume MA. You can create an alert on it and
>    type in a message box something like this:
>
> Volume: {{plot_0}}, Volume average: {{plot_1}}

Read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000531021-how-to-use-a-variable-value-in-alert/) for more details.